# Is Hex Schmitt Trigger Inverter IC (74C14 ) same as CD40106BE Inverter, Schmitt Trigger, CD40106, 1 Input, 3V to 18V, DIP-14

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am following an online tutorial. It needs `Hex Schmitt Trigger Inverter IC (74C14 )` but I can't find it anywhere. Instead, I can see `CD40106BE Inverter, Schmitt Trigger, CD40106, 1 Input, 3V to 18V, DIP-14`

Are the both the same? I want to create a simple inverter circuit (batter, capcitor, LED and invertor). Blink an LED. Nothing to fancy.

[image]

See this - https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/build-blinking-light-circuit/?tl_inbound=1&tl_target_all=1&tl_form_type=1&tl_period_type=3&utm_source=convertkit&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Lesson+7%3A+How+to+build+the+circuit%20-%202416744

Comment: They are both CMOS, they are the same.

Comment: No, the 74C series and the CD4000 series are both plain CMOS parts. However, these two parts are not the same. Whether their differences are significant to **you** depends on your application, and you haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: my bad. Updated the question. I am making a simple circuit (please see updated question)

Comment: For your se they are close to functionally equivalent. The 40106 has a smaller hysteresis range than the C14 so will oscillate at a higher frequency in this circuit. A minor point in this case

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same. You can download the datasheets for both chips and compare them in which way they are same or different.

Comment: Depending on the application in your tutorial, you may able to use 74HC14, 74ACT14, 74AHCT14. Not enough information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

TI says that the CD40106B is a drop-in replacement:
[bomcross.ti.com/en/search?searchTerm=74C14](https://bomcross.ti.com/en/search?searchTerm=74C14&selectedRow=7)

Some electrical characteristics (hysteresis, drive strength, speed) are somewhat different, but for most applications, this should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the 74C14 is intended to be a compatible replacement for the 40106, but there are some significant differences, which I gleaned from the datasheets ([40106](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40106b.pdf?ts=1631775822594), [74C14](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/mm74c14-1193355.pdf)):

- Power supply range for the 40106 is greater, up to 20V compared to 15V for the 74C14.
- For the 40106, trigger thresholds are about 40% and 60% of Vdd. For the 74C14 it's more like 30% and 70% Vdd. If the device is being used as relaxation oscillator, or in some timing role where the thresholds are critical, these differences will be problematic.
- The 74C14 is able to sink and source 5 times more output current than the 40106.
- Somewhat unusally for 4xxx series devices, the input-to-output propagation delay of the 40106 is slightly smaller (better) than the 74C14, although the difference is minimal.
- The 40106 has output transitions taking anywhere between 40 and 100 nanoseconds, depending on supply voltage. I couldn't find transition times for the 74C14, but they will probably be better due to its higher output drive capability.

I wouldn't call either one a "drop-in replacement" for the other, but that could certainly be true in many applications.